# Create a empty geopackage with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, geopackage

I'm trying to create a new GeoPackage with an empty layer in it. I tried this code from this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417916/creating-empty-layers-in-a-geopackage-using-pyqgis).

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

layer_name = 'my_layer'
gpkg_path = 'test.gpkg'
geom = QgsWkbTypes.MultiPolygon
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('epsg:4326')
tc = QgsCoordinateTransformContext()
schema = QgsFields()
schema.append(QgsField('double_field', QVariant.Double))
schema.append(QgsField('text_field', QVariant.String))
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "GPKG"
options.layerName = layer_name
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.create(gpkg_path, schema, geom, crs, tc, options)
assert writer.hasError() == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError
del writer  # to flush
```

But I can't read it

```
lyr = QgsVectorLayer('test.gpkg', 'my_layer', 'ogr')
assert lyr.isValid()  # False instead of true
```

In QGIS, the test GeoPackage have no layers inside instead of 'my_layer' as expected.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Line `schema.append(QgsField('double_field', QVariant.Double))
` is freezing my QGIS and I can only kill it from operating system. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I was using pyqgis standalone. If you are inside QGIS remove the 4 first lines.

Comment: No problem with ogrinfo `Open of 'test.gpkg' using driver 'GPKG' successful. 1: my_layer (Multi Polygon)`. Also attributes double_field and text_field are there. Maybe QGIS wants to get extent or feature count or something  that is does not get from an empty layer. But GeoPackage seems OK to me.

Comment: Not with my setup.

    javier@urano:~/osm-es/CatAtom2Osm/results$ ogrinfo test2.gpkg
    INFO: Open of `test2.gpkg'
          using driver `GPKG' successful.
    1: prueba (Multi Polygon)
    javier@urano:~/osm-es/CatAtom2Osm/results$ ogrinfo test.gpkg
    INFO: Open of `test.gpkg'
          using driver `GPKG' successful.

test2.gpkg was created inside QGIS with the menus. 
test.gpkg was created with the code.

Comment: Did you run your code inside QGIS like I did by following your advice? The result for me is a completely valid GeoPackage according to the GDAL script validate_gpkg.py.  And I do have a row in gpkg_contents.

Comment: With sqlite3, 
$ sqlite3 test.gpkg "select count(*) from gpkg_contents" -> 0
$ sqlite3 test2.gpkg "select count(*) from gpkg_contents" -> 1

Comment: I tried inside QGIS with the same results. Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS   QGIS 3.10.4-A Coruña 'A Coruña'

Comment: QGIS 3.18 on Windows, having GDAL 3.1.4. Does the SQLite connection get closed for you so that there are no changes in a queue in a wal file?

Comment: Tests was done in completely different directories.

Comment: So no wal files hanging around in the same directory than where the .gpkg exixts when you did `select count() from gpkg_contents`?

Comment: Right. QGIS writes output file in my home directory (~). The standalone script in another one (~/dev/myprogram).

Comment: Strange. Anyway it works for me so I think that your code is OK. For you it creates the database but does not insert a line into gpkg_contents. How about the table itself, is "my_layer" created? Have you tried a newer QGIS version?

Comment: Final suggestion: test with debug on `ogrinfo test.gpkg --debug on`. I can see that before the final row `del writer  # to flush` is executed the test.gpkg database is locked for other connections. Spatialite-gui does not open it because it says that database is used by another process. And ogrinfo with debug prints a misleading message `GPKG: This GeoPackage has no vector content and is opened in read-only mode. If you open it in update mode, opening will be successful.`  Once "del writer" is run the gpkg file is OK for GDAL and spatialite-gui.

Comment: Thank you for your Comments. I will try to run the code with another QGIS setup to compare

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar case right now.

My solution was to remove `options.layerName` attribute (it can be defined in `QgsVectorLayer`), set `QgsVectorFileWriter.create()` as a separate variable and then delete it.

The full code:

```
out_layer = r'D:\GIS\Терпланирование\sheet_folder\demo5.gpkg'
schema = QgsFields()
schema.append(QgsField('id', QVariant.Int))

crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('epsg:4326')
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "GPKG"
options.fileEncoding = 'cp1251'

fw = QgsVectorFileWriter.create(
    fileName=out_layer,
    fields=schema,
    geometryType=QgsWkbTypes.Polygon,
    srs=crs,
    transformContext=QgsCoordinateTransformContext(),
    options=options)
del fw 
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\GIS\Терпланирование\sheet_folder\demo5.gpkg", 'my_layer', 'ogr')    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```